# MariaDB 10.6.3 fails to start after enabling File Key Management Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb, tde, mariadb-10.6

I'm trying to enable File Key Management encryption in MariaDB 10.6.3 server (Rocky Linux). I'm generating key file using open ssl. I have followed this guide https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/mariadb-encryption-tde-using-mariadbs-file-key-management-encryption-plugin/

```
echo "1;"$(openssl rand -hex 32) > /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile
openssl rand -hex 128 > /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
```

While generating encrypted file using

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1 -pass file:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key -in /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile -out /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
```

I'm getting a warning

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
```

Since the above code was generating a warning, I used

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 
 -pass file:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key -in /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile -out /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
```

This is the configuration I have added in server.cnf

```
#File Key Management Plugin
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR

# InnoDB Encryption Setup
innodb_encrypt_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
innodb_encryption_threads = 4
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops = 2000

# Temp & Log Encryption
encrypt_tmp_disk_tables = ON
encrypt_tmp_files = ON
encrypt_binlog = ON
aria_encrypt_tables = ON
```

After saving the configuration, when I try to restart MariaDB it fails to start. MariaDB Status produces

```
[ERROR] mariadbd: Cannot decrypt /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc. Wrong key?
[ERROR] Plugin 'file_key_management' init function returned error.


[ERROR] Plugin 'file_key_management' registration as a ENCRYPTION failed.
[ERROR] InnoDB: cannot enable encryption, encryption plugin is not available
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Failed to enable encryption of temporary files
[ERROR] Aborting
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.6.3 database server.
```

I have checked /var/lib/mysql/ and file_key_management.so file is available.

I'm sure that the addition of `-pbkdf2 -iter 100000` is the problem.

Can anyone tell me where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The things goes wrong when file_key_management plugin doesn't support newer formats and different key derivation method. But it might in the future, see [this bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20181).

For now you need to follow the instructions for encrypting the key file:

> There are some important details to keep in mind about encrypting the key file, such as:
> The only algorithm that MariaDB currently supports to encrypt the key file is Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode of Advanced Encryption Standard (AES).
> The encryption key size can be 128-bits, 192-bits, or 256-bits.
> The encryption key is created from the SHA-1 hash of the encryption password.
> The encryption password has a max length of 256 characters.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/#encrypting-the-key-file

```
$ sudo openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1 \
-pass file:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key \
-in /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile \
-out /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
```

If you encrypt with -aes-256-cbc make sure that the file_key_management_encryption_algorithm is **not** set to AES_CTR.

Good luck!